# Drupal 7 Search Module Increase snippet result

Tags: search, module, drupal-7

I want to increase my snippet result. When I'm going to print . It display few data from the content along with "..." 3 dots. Please help me to increase the snippet result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. In your search-result.tpl.php file.
Try to find the value of your body from result array and mentioned in under node_load function. For ex:- node_load($result['node']->entity_id)->body['und'][0]['value'];

This will fetch all the results. :)